# A function. Really?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, number-property

> If you give me a 5, I give you a 21.
> If you give me a 6, I give you a 2.
> If you give me a 7, I give you a 12.
> If you give me a 10, I give you a 101.

What am I processing to get the result?

### Hint 1

> If you give me a 3, I give you a 1.

### Hint 2

> This has some thing to do with a reversed 3.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not a maths problem, it has just a bit to do with numbers.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the answer is

> The number in base 3, with the digits reversed.

So 5 is

> 12 base 3, reversed is 21

6 is

> 20 base 3 reversed is 02 (drop the leading 0)

7 is

> 21 base 3, reversed is 12

And 10 is

> 101 base 3, same reversed.

Comment: What????????????? In less than a minute?

Comment: Would have taken me longer without hint 2. I was mostly there anyway, but hint 2 just made it obvious.

Comment: Sorry, can accept only in 10 minutes.